# libssh (C++): Possible to redirect some output from some given `fd` to an `ssh_channel` on remote side?

Tags: android, c++, linux, file-descriptor, libssh

Using the `libssh` library, one can communicate with a remote host by opening a channel:

```
// Assume authentication for sshSession has been completed
ssh_channel channel_to_remote = ssh_channel_new(sshSession);
ssh_channel_open_session(channel_to_remote)
```

Does this channel happen to have a file descriptor that I can access on the remote side? If I have a file descriptor that is already open on my local side, is it possible to use the channel to notify the remote host about the file descriptor?

I have a ready-made executable that I wish to run on the remote side, and this executable writes output to a specific file descriptor (let us call it `fd` 3). Is it possible to redirect this output from `fd` 3 to the channel?

Cheers in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Tutorial for libssh is [here](https://api.libssh.org/stable/libssh_tutorial.html).

Use a combination of `dup()` and `ssh_channel_callbacks_struct`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This more of a comment than an answer.